# How can we make the visit counter increment by only 1 instead of 2 for a particular event?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When we implement a visit counter in Node.js, the count is incremented by 2 as one for calling web server and one for loading Favicon so in total it makes two. 
I am using following code to implement visit count.

```
var http = require('http');
var userCount = 0;
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    userCount++;
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.write('Hello!\n');
    res.write('We have had ' + userCount + ' visits!\n');
    res.end();
 
});
server.listen(9090);
console.log('server running...')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you visit a url,
most browsers send an additional request to get `/favicon.ico` to use in tab headers.
This is a distinct HTTP request, as far as the web server is concerned.

If you want to exclude requests for `/favicon.ico` from the count,
add a filter on `req.url`:

```
if (req.url !== '/favicon.ico') {
    userCount++;
}
```

Note if you output an HTML with references to style sheets and images,
a browser will send additional HTTP requests for each of those.